# What devices are used to boost a UTP copper ethernet signal?

Tags: lan, cabling

The signal at source is tolerable at a peak of 6 mb/s, but from the server room to other network switches in other buildings, figure a distance of say a football field, it's terrible. You can barely use it and it keeps dropping. Is there anything out that can be installed in the network cabinet in addition to the switches and routers that can amplify the UTP copper signal to other areas from the source, which in my case is a server room.

If there is no device what would you recommend?

NB: The signal is received by radio from the ISP but to the other buildings we have a wired UTP LAN network connection.

Comment: "football field" (let's 150 m) is length of Ethernet cable or wireless link?

Comment: Yes apologies. Cables only.

Comment: You don't specify which kind of radio link it is... 3G? 802.11 WiFi? LTE?  This would help. Also note 6 Mb/s isn't really signal, but bandwidth or throughput. For best answers, you're going to need to get into the device (or have ISP do so) and get your "signal strength" and "signal to noise ratio". Without that, you only have bandwidth (or throughput, not sure which you're providing), which is the SYMPTOM of your signal, but not your signal. Bandwidth relies on signal strength and SNR, not vice-versa.

Comment: If it question about LAN only wired link, change topic. On "How to connect two Ethernet switches over 150 meters" for example. Or "How to improve connection between two Ethernet switches over 150 meters chopper twisted pair"

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5):

If the problem is on a long UTP copper cable pinned for ethernet, there are some solutions.

1. Change the copper UTP cable to Single-Mode Fiber. It solves not only the distance problem, but it also eliminates possible problems due to different electrical potential between buildings.
2. Add an Ethernet switch in middle of link, splitting the link into 2 parts, <=100m each; ethernet switches can regenerate the signal. FYI, the switch even can be powered by PoE from one of sides. (e.g. a Mikrotik RB260G)
3. Use G.SHDSL.bis modem. It gives you up to 11 Mbit on 2 copper pairs; however, it's not very cheap and not very fast. The advantage is the ability to work on UTP copper runs of roughly 1 to 5 km.  You could also use another kind of Ethernet Cable Extender, I googled one up to 100 Mbit.
4. Ugly Russian solution: Use old 3COM switches (without MDII-MDX auto-sensing) it has a reputation of high sensitive/high power device. (I don't recommend this, because it is not guaranteed to work.)
5. Use minimal as possible cross commutation in this link. Ideally, crimp RJ45 (8P8C) directly on the cable and put it in the switch.
6. Tighter wires and higher category cabling is better. However, if you need to install new cables, fiber optics are strongly advised between buildings.
7. Partial solution: Try configuring this link as Half-duplex rather than Full-duplex, or 10 Mbit rather 100 Mbit. (Half-duplex can lower importance of NEXT interference).

PS. Solutions 4,5, and 6 are ugly because it's non-standard. 7 also, because it is really a broken link. Choose wisely.

Comment: Nothing about this is "standard" if the link is over 100m. He has little choice but to switch to fiber.

Comment: Also note: the spec says 100m, but a great deal of ethernet hardware out there cannot power a link that long.

Comment: Technically it is 90m for the run and an additional 10m to cover the patches on both sides.  100m only if you are counting end to end.  I know this is "nitpicking," but I don't want to count the times I have come across places where they installed up to 100m because "so and so said 100m was the standard.:

Comment: True, "100m *node to node*" is the exact words from the spec. (and a switch, or *bridge* as they were called back then, counts as a node.)